# How to change form input button to anchor a href?

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

I want to change my site design using html/css template. My site code is using form input as logout button (submit form post method) but the template I have using anchor as the button.
How I can still use the template style but still working button?

I've tried changing `<input>` to `<button>` but still the style is different also 
putting 'method' and 'action' seems not valid for anchor.

below is my code

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
<input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
```

and this is code from the template

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger">
<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
</a>
```

I expect a href can also do action post method.

Comment: Anything you don't want a search engine to trigger shouldn't be a link, of you want your log out button to look like a link then just use CSS to make the `<button>` element look like an `<a>` element.

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger">
<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
</button>`

Comment: A link can only trigger a GET request, not a POST request. You'd have to trigger the post request via JavaScript, or style the button to look like a text link, e.g. `<button type="submit" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</button>` (you'll probably need to override some button default styles, too)

Comment: I'm fully aware that I can't use `<a>` to request a POST method. But still I want use the similar style as the template.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer while looking at Laravel default app.blade.php.
To solve the problem I must modify my code and add some javascript to become like this

```
          <a class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
          </a>
          <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger">
<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
<input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
</a>
```

Comment: result still showing button, different from template style.